# jquery-ui / widgets and references via options

Tags: jquery, widget

I came upon a strange issue with jQuery widgets.

Here is what I tried to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/erazor/kc1122cs/

More or less I'd like to have a master widget who creates slave widgets and these are able to manipulate an array.
I create the array in the master and supply it to each slave. Now the slave can change it's data and the master "should" have access to it too.

The issue is, that (what I assume) jQuery does some kind of copy/clone of the options before the _create is called. Is that right? Did I somehow miss it in the documentation?

I there a way to work-around this?

A possible way would be to get the instance of the widget after creation and then set the data directly?
like:

```
var wdg_inst=$('#widget_holder').test_widget('instance');
wdg_inst.Data=...;
wdg_inst.handleData();
```

Anyway, it'd be easier to somehow pass a reference directly on creation.

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

I came across some similar problem. As far as i understood it, there is some clone operation involved burried inside $.widget.extend that creates a separate options object inside each widget instance. 
My workaround was to wrap the access to the global options object with a function and pass that to the widget.

```
$.widget("custom.test_widget", {
  options: {
    valueFunc: null

  },
  _getOpts: function() {
    if (typeof this.options.valueFunc==='function') {
      return this.options.valueFunc();
    }
    return {};
  },
  _create: function() {
    var opts = this._getOpts();
    opts['a'] = 10;
  }
});

var widget_value = {};
var opts = function() {
  return widget_value;
}

$('#widget_holder').test_widget({
  valueFunc: opts
});
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kbebqaag/7/

I don't know if this is suitable for your use case.

Comment: thanks, but that's even more overhead IMHO. But it's good to see others noticed the "cloning" too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use a separate function for setting/modding the value.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/erazor/5h5a0wvq/4/

```
$.widget( "custom.test_widget", {
  options: {
    value: null
  },
  _create: function() {
  },
  setAndMod: function(value) {
    this.options.value=value;
    this.options.value['a']=10;
  }
});

var widget_value={};
console.log('value before widget init',widget_value);
$('#widget_holder').test_widget({});
$('#widget_holder').test_widget('setAndMod',widget_value);
console.log('value after widget init',widget_value);
```